# Ayuda con radio button, ¿Cómo usar la validación?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas, estoy muy pez en esto, a pesar de que he visto varios vídeos y he leído varias páginas no lo tengo del todo claro, de todas formas he intentado hacerlo pero algo he hecho mal, no está funcionando además estoy recibiendo este error:

Warning: mysql_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in blocks.php on line 26

```
...
26 mysql_free_result($result_next)
...
```

Estoy editando tanto el código form como el php en el mismo archivo (blocks.php) porque ya estoy acumulando demasiados archivos externos.
¿Alguien sabría decirme que he puesto mal? Muchas gracias.

Hay una tabla llamada blocks y lo que quiero es cambiar el valor de 'active' mediante un radiobutton yes/no que insertaría 1/0 depende de lo elegido

Tabla:

```
id  title                content_file   content_html    language   sort_order   active
1   Next Events          next_events                    english          1           1
2   Last Race            last_race                      english          2           1
3   Standings            standings                      english          3           1
```

blocks.php:

```
<? if(!defined("CONFIG")) exit();
if(!isset($login)) { show_error("You do not have administrator rights\n"); return; }
        require_once("session_start.php");
        ?>
        <!--Next events block-->
        <h1>Next events</h1>
        <form action="blocks.php" method="post"> 
        Activate:
      <input type="radio" name="active_next" <?php if (isset($active_next) && $active_next=="1") echo "checked";?> value="1">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="active_next" <?php if (isset($active_next) && $active_next=="0") echo "checked";?> value="0">No
       &nbsp;
       </b> </b> <input type="submit" name="submit_next" value="Set">
      <br><br> 
    </form>

    <?PHP
    mysqlconnect();

    if (isset($_POST['active_next'])){
    $query_next = "UPDATE blocks SET active='$active_next' WHERE content_file='$next_events'";
    $result_next = mysql_query($query_next);
    if(!$result_next) error("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error() . "\n");

    return_do(".?page=blocks", "activated succesfully modified\n$msg");}
    mysql_free_result($result_next)

    ?>
```

No termino de entender como usar una validación, que creo que es lo que me falta.

Por otro lado quisiera consejos para buscar un colaborador. Ya que el proyecto es GPLv3, no es comercial, ni para uso personal, es un manager para liga online de carrera, así que no hay remuneración, lo inicié junto con un amigo programador y es una mejora de uno GPLv2 ya obsoleto. Mi amigo inició varias features, pero debido a falta de tiempo el proyecto ha quedado parado y yo intento terminar las cosas hasta donde puedo, mis conocimientos son muy limitados.
¿Dónde puedo buscar colaboradores? ¿tengo que tomar alguna precaución por si la persona quiere hacer alguna jugarreta?, gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado, me faltaba definir el valor de la variable puesta en la consulta SET active='$active_next' con el valor dado por el formulario.

```
    $active_next = $_POST["active_next"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que ocupas `mysql_free_result` ? Esta funcion esta obsoleta desde php 5.5 y eliminada de php 7.0. Ademas esta función liberaba memoria de un resultado. Entiendo que tu consulta tu haces un `UPDATE` por lo tanto no recibes una respuesta como la que recibes de un SELECT (que sea necesario liberar memoria)

```
if (isset($_POST['active_next'])) {
    $query_next = "UPDATE blocks SET active='$active_next' WHERE content_file='$next_events'";
    $result_next = mysql_query($query_next);
    if (!$result_next) error("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error()."\n");

    return_do(".?page=blocks", "activated succesfully modified\n$msg");
}
```

Comment: Me dijeron que si todas las consultas las dejo sin el mysql_free_result la memoria sql se llenará.
Pero tiene sentido ahora que me lo dices, si es update no está llenando la memoria con una consulta.
Lo que me propusiste hace que ya no tenga el aviso de error pero sigue sin funcionarme, hice algunos cambios pero no hace nada:

Comment: Te dijeron mal, ya que libera la memoria solo el valor de la consulta. @arv187  y como te dije, esta obsoleta

Comment: blocks.php:
`<!--Next events block-->
<?

    mysqlconnect();

    if (isset($_POST['active_next'])) {
    $query_next = "UPDATE blocks SET active='$active_next' WHERE content_file='$next_events'";
    $result_next = mysql_query($query_next);
    if (!$result_next) error("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error()."\n");

    echo "activated succesfully modified\n$msg";
}else{ ?>`

Comment: `<h1>Next events</h1>
        <form action="blocks.php" method="post"> 
        Activate:
      <input type="radio" name="active_next" <?php if (isset($active_next) && $active_next=="1") echo "checked";?> value="1">Yes
      <input type="radio" name="active_next" <?php if (isset($active_next) && $active_next=="0") echo "checked";?> value="0">No
       &nbsp;
       </b> </b> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Set">
      <br><br> 
    </form>
<? } ?>`

Comment: ??? Que es ese codigo

Comment: Es la modificación que hice ya que también me comentaron que $result_next está vacío y para evitar ese error tenía que validar las operaciones con if y else

Comment: Sigo sin entender, que ocurre ahora?

Comment: Ahora selecciono una opción yes/no y me lleva a la página blocks.php en lugar de ?page=blocks (la correcta), pero se muestra vacía, y en la base de datos no ha cambiado el valor active.